Covert large JSON files with dynamic schema to csv in Java or shell
I want to covert large JSON files to CSV. The files have multiple JSON objects and can be nested. These files are large (1 to 10 GB), so it would not be possible to load them in memory . Also the files have different schema's so the structure for CSV may vary.
One option is to iterate over the files using streams API of say Jackson, get all the fields that need to be created to define the csv structure, then use the jq command to convert it to csv. Is there a better way to do this ?

Do objects have array fields?

And the top-level? is it an array?

Yes objects have array fields and at top level they are arrays

How do you want to deal with the array fields?
